# Sending HTML Email results in Email displaying HTML source (Codeigniter)

Tags: codeigniter

When I submit the form information, the form is successfully sent, but I'm receiving mail in HTML-type format, I mean I'm receiving email in the HTML format instead of this format( picture-1). Where I'm making a mistake, I'm new in Codeigniter.

my controller code is this -

[image]

The function is this - I read different - different articles on this, and applied different - different methods but didn't work, sometimes, I got an error on the sending form page, and sometimes it sent the email in the same HTML format. Can you please look into the code, and let me know where and how can I fix this.

```
        protected function send_email($to,$subject,$message,$from_email = '')
{
    if(empty($from_email)) $from_email = SUPPORT_EMAIL;
    if(EMAIL_GATEWAY == 'phpmailer'){
        $headers = "From: " . C('site_name') . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$from_email . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "CC: ".$from_email."\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        $result = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        return $result;
    }
    elseif(EMAIL_GATEWAY =='cpanel_mailer'){
        $mail = new PHPMailer(); 
        $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
        $mail->Host = CHOST;
        $mail->Port = 465;
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Username = CUSERNAME;
        $mail->Password = CPASSWORD;
        $mail->SetFrom(CUSERNAME);
        $mail->FromName=CSENDERNAME;
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body = $message;
        $mail->AddAddress($to);
        if(!$mail->Send()) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else if(EMAIL_GATEWAY=='gmail'){

        $mail = new PHPMailer(); 
        $mail->IsSMTP(); 
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0; 
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
        $mail->Host = EHOST;
        $mail->Port = 465;
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Username = EUSERNAME;
        $mail->Password = EPASSWORD;
        $mail->SetFrom(EUSERNAME);
        $mail->FromName=C('site_name');
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body = $message;
        $mail->AddAddress($to);
        if(!$mail->Send()) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else{
        $config = array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => SMTP_HOST,
            'smtp_user' => SMTP_USER,
            'smtp_pass' => SMTP_PASS,
            'smtp_port' => SMTP_PORT,
            'mailtype' => 'html',
            'charset'=>'iso-8859-1',
            'crlf'=>'\r\n',
            'newline'=>'\r\n',
            'smtp_timeout' => 30,
            'smtp_crypto'=>'tls'
        );
        $this->load->library('email',$config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->from(SMTP_SENDER, C('site_name'));
        $this->email->to($to, 'Test To');
        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($message);

        if($this->email->send()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
            //print_r($this->email->print_debugger());
        }
    }

}
protected function send_email_ses($to,$subject,$message){

    $config = array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => SMTP_HOST,
        'smtp_user' => SMTP_USER,
        'smtp_pass' => SMTP_PASS,
        'smtp_port' => SMTP_PORT,
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'charset'=>'utf-8',
        'crlf'=>"\r\n",
        'newline'=>"\r\n",
        'smtp_timeout' => 30,
        'smtp_crypto'=>'tls'
    );
    $this->load->library('email',$config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from(SMTP_SENDER, 'GetAppInstall');
    $this->email->to($to, 'Test To');
    $this->email->subject($subject);
    $this->email->message($message);

    if($this->email->send()){
        return;
    }else{
        return;
        //print_r($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
}
```